# Regex lookbehind not work as expected when combine with boundary

Tags: regex

Iam investigating the look behind regex following this reference:
[regexinfo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

And the engine to test: [engine to text regex](https://regex101.com/)

Assume i have this regex using lookbehind:

```
(?<=a)b
```

The input text will be "ab". This regex work fine and match 'b' in "ab". But when i add a word boundary to the regex:

```
\b(?<=a)b\b
```

Then the regex will not match the 'b' in "ab" anymore. But i didn't see any different here.
I can explain the work flow of the regex engine here:

- The "\b" in the regex will match the start of the string "ab"
- Then the `(?<=a)` will start at the 'a' in "ab", it look behind to find 'a' and can't find 'a' so it move to the next position that is 'b'. Here it look behind and found 'a' so it stop the lookbehind, the current character is 'b' also matches the "b" in the regex so the regex must return the match result that is 'b' but no matches found.

Did i misunderstanding about this situation?

Comment: The lookbehind has no ‘width’, so you’re trying to match `\bb\b`. (Or so I think, correct me if I’m wrong.)

Comment: You're missing an equal sign `=` in your second regex `\b(?<a)b\b`. It should be `\b(?<=a)b\b`

Comment: my mistake for missing the sign "=", i updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im still confused about the answer of @revo so i try to dive deeper about the way the Regex engine work and also the detail of word boundaries "\b". I found these reference is very helpful:

[how Regex engine works reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

[word boundary reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

So with my regex : `\b(?<=a)b\b` and my input `"ab"` i can explain by the way the Regex engine work:

- Step1: The Regex engine stand at 'a' in string "ab", i try to match the token "\b" with the previous character of 'a' that is the void character. This matches so the engine advances to the next position in the regex that is the look behind "(?<=a)"
- Step2: current position of the string still 'a', the look behind try to find 'a' character before the current 'a' but that is void character and the match failed, The engine then move to next position of the string that is 'b'
- Step3: The engine try to match the first token '\b' of the regex with 'b', this failed.

So "ab" can match with the regex pattern "\b(?<-a)b\b

Answer (score 1):

First of all your lookbehind misses a type identifier it should be `(?<=...)`. Secondly, let's remove lookbehind:

```
\bb\b
```

This means a `b`, alone. Boundaries doesn't allow any following or preceding letter or digit be at either sides of a character of the same type (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Now let's put lookbehind back:

```
\b(?<=a)b\b
```

This matches a word boundary (where a word character doesn't meet another word character - or - start of word) then looks for a preceding `a` that never comes. Before `b` never can a letter or digit come because of word boundary so this never matches. It always fails.